# copy all xml nodes and rename few in them using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an XML, in that XML I have an element <storybody> which itself have several elements, now what I want is copy every in <storybody> and change <URI> tag in <storybody> with <a>.

Remember I need to do this for only <storybody> in document.

XML Structure:

```xml
<mothertag>
     <atag>
        asdfasdfa
     </atag>

     <storybody>
        <p>sometext here<URI ref="http://google.com" /> some more text</p>
     </storybody>
</mothertag>
```

Now I want to change this URI to a tag.

Comment: Can you provide an example of exactly what you're expecting the output to be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need an **[identity transformation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_transform)** augmented with additional templates to match nodes you want renamed. Like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />
    <xsl:output indent="yes" method="html" />

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>   

    <xsl:template match="URI">
        <TAG>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </TAG>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to (corrected the typo in the closing `storybody` tag):

```
<mothertag>
     <atag>
        asdfasdfa
     </atag>

     <storybody>
        <p>sometext here<URI ref="http://google.com" /> some more text</p>
     </storybody>

</mothertag>
```

Produces:

```
<mothertag>
   <atag>
      asdfasdfa

   </atag>
   <storybody>
      <p>sometext here
         <TAG ref="http://google.com"></TAG> some more text
      </p>
   </storybody>
</mothertag>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, just a step ahead of this, if I have a <unwanted> tag inside <storybody> i.e. i dont want to copy all the nodes in inside <storybody>
Thanks for correcting typo :)

Comment: @Touseef, you can silent the unwanted tags with empty tempaltes. like this `<xsl:template match="unwanted"/>`. btw, if the answer helped you please also consider upvoting it. Thanks