# copy all xml nodes and rename few in them using XSLT 2

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an XML, in that XML i have an element which itself have several elements, now what i want is copy every in and change tag name.

XML Structure:

```
<mothertag>
     <atag>
        asdfasdfa
     </atag>

     <storybody>
        <p>sometext here<URI ref="http://google.com" /> some more text</p>
     </storybody>

</mothertag>
```

1. I want to change name `<storybody>` to `<body>`,
2. everything else should be as it is and change the `<URI>` to `<a>`

what i am doing for rest of the document is defining the templates and applying one by one. now i encountered this one which is needed to copied as it is with few changes and name changed.

Comment: Look at the `<xsl:copy>` and `<xsl:copy-of>` instructions.

Comment: possible duplicate of [copy all xml nodes and rename few in them using XSLT](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10533543/copy-all-xml-nodes-and-rename-few-in-them-using-xslt)

Comment: Is the `<URI>` attribute really `ref` or is it actually `href`?

Answer (score 0):

To do this in XSLT all you need is a basic identity transform, with an exception for the `<storybody>` elements.

Something like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="storybody">
    <body>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </body>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

**Edit**

I have read your comment, *"I don't want to use identity transform. Rather I need to use identity transform on one element in the document"*, and am unclear what you need. Perhaps you have the transform for the rest of the document OK but are having trouble with this element? In that case you should use just the second template from my answer in addition to what you have already written.

The second part of your message was partly lost in the markup but has now been fixed and I overlooked it. To change the `<URI>` element to an `<a>` as well you should add another template. Assuming you want to change the original `ref` attribute to `href`, the two together look like this

```
<xsl:template match="storybody">
  <body>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </body>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="storybody//URI">
  <a>
    <xsl:attribute name="href">
      <xsl:value-of select="@ref" />
    </xsl:attribute>
  </a>
</xsl:template>
```

If your intention was something different from this, please clarify and we will help you further.

Comment: actually I dont want to use identity transform. rather i need to use identity transform on one element in the document.

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear what you are trying to do Touseef without an example of your desired result XML but....

If what you need is to throw away most of your input document and just keep one tag then this pattern may help:

```
 <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

   <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
       <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="storybody">
       <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
   </xsl:template>

 </xsl:stylesheet>
```

I am not in front of a machine with an XSLT engine as I type so I have not tested this. But the idea is to match everything with the first template and simply ignore it except for the storybody element which we simply copy to the output document.

If this doesn't help then I urge you to provide a sample desired result XML document and a clear statement of the rules you wish to apply